# Which STL containers require the use of CAdapt?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, containers

The [`CAdapt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs6acf5x.aspx) class is provided by Microsoft in order to enable using classes that override the address of operator (`operator&`) in STL containers. MSDN has this to say about the use of `CAdapt`:

> Typically, you will use `CAdapt` when you want to store `CComBSTR`, `CComPtr`, `CComQIPtr`, or `_com_ptr_t` objects in an STL container such as a `list`.

On to my quesiton:

**What is the full list of STL containers with which `CAdapt` should be used?**

If the container contains a key/value pair (such as `map`) please specify whether `CAdapt` is needed for the key or the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the full list of STL containers with which CAdapt should be used?

None. Implementations should assume operator& is overloaded, and use the correct expression `&reinterpret_cast<char&>(obj)`

Now, there is another question that you didn't ask:

> My VC++ STL implementation doesn't agree. It does provide `CAdapt` as a workaround. What is the full list of its containers with which CAdapt should be used?

Top of my head, I'd day `vector<T>` (stores them as a `T[]` so reasonably needs arithmetic on them) and deque (stores them as multiple smaller `T[]`s so same rationale). list, map, set, multiset and multimap all work on nodes, so they themselves already wrap each object.

Comment: Except for vector<bool>, which uses a proxy object.

Comment: Is `&reinterpret_cast<char&>` well defined on any object?

Comment: @Motti: yes, the idea is from ISO C++ WG paper N1324 by Jens Maurer, in response to CWG DR273 (`offsetof` has the same problem).

Answer (score 2):

Another thing from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs6acf5x.aspx):

The adapter class CAdapt is useful because many container classes (such as the STL container classes) **expect to be able to obtain the addresses of their contained objects** using the address-of operator.strong text.

I don't think you'll find a list of containers that have this requirement. This sounds like implementation dependent to me.